# increase users to display in who is new block

Tags: 7, blocks

I need to display more than 10 users in who is new block, i see the dropdown list has at max 10.

So, how can I increase it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options I see:

- Recreate this block with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) - changes like that are the very sense of their existence.
- Create custom module with hook_form_alter() and add numbers up to some arbitrary max you prefer. Note that it might be a performance hit that way, if block in question loads full user objects. To much and you'll eat your memory.

Comment: there is already block in drupal 7 i do not need to create new one.

Comment: Well, Views are generally for people who "like the default _______, but want to __________ differently". Looked like your case.